# Вывод текста объекта

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Необходимо вывести текст объекта.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = Chrome('')
url = ''
getBrowser = browser.get(url)
bal = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tdt-transactions- 
             table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/text()')
print(bal)
```

Выдаёт исключение:

> _*selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalidselector: The result of the xpath expression
> "//*[@id="tdt-transactions-table"]/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFKE7.png)/td[3]/text()" is:
> [object Text]. It should be an element.*

Фрагмент HTML кода: [image]

Как вывести значение из красного прямоугольника?

Comment: Меня метод find_element смущает - вполне сочетается с сообщением об ошибке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой текст из элемента добывается методом .text. Так как получается строка со всеми встреченными текстовыми элементами, то разбиваем ее в список и распечатываем нужный элемент.

```
bal = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tdt-transactions- 
             table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text.split()
print(bal[?])
```